# Excel VBA Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have `Range("A1:A4")` names and `Range("B1:B4")` as grades. I need to their status in `Range("C1:C4")` . I have used `Select Case` in VBA for this, but it is throwing an error:

> Runtime error 13 , type mismatch

```
Sub Grades()

Dim mark As Integer

mark = Range("B1:B4").Value

Select Case mark

Case 0 To 35
Range("C1:C4").Value = "Fail"

Case 36 To 59
Range("C1:C4").Value = "Pass"

Case 60 To 79
Range("C1:C4").Value = "Class"

Case 80 To 89
Range("C1:C4").Value = "Distinction"

Case 90 To 100
Range("C1:C4").Value = "Excellent"

Case Else
MsgBox "no text entered"

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: `mark = Range("B1:B4").Value` you set `mark` as int then try to store array to it. Edit: you can do a `for each e in mark` followed by your case statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Range("B1:B4").Value` will return an array and therefore won't work with a `Select Case` block.

You need to loop through each value in order to evaluate it separately:

```
For Each cell In Range("B1:B4").Cells
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case 0 To 35:   Range("C" & cell.Row).Value = "Fail"
        Case 36 To 59:  Range("C" & cell.Row).Value = "Pass"
        Case 60 To 79:  Range("C" & cell.Row).Value = "Class"
        Case 80 To 89:  Range("C" & cell.Row).Value = "Distinction"
        Case 90 To 100: Range("C" & cell.Row).Value = "Excellent"
        Case Else:      MsgBox "No text entered"
    End Select
Next
```

Even better - would be simply assign a formula and re-write the value:

```
With Range("C1:C4")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]>0,IF(RC[-1]<36,"Fail",IF(RC[-1]<60,"Pass",IF(RC[-1]<80,"Class",IF(RC[-1]<90,"Distinction",IF(RC[-1]<=100,"Excellent"))))),"No Value Entered")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: re: formula based solution: I'm pretty certain that the *"No text entered"* will never be reached unless column B has a zero-length string returned by a formula. A truly blank cell would be a *"Fail"*.

Comment: ^ Oh snap. Removing my upvote. Edit: this is what you get for being snobby =P

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @findwindow's comment, here is code that will work.

```
Sub Grades()

    Dim mark() As Variant
    Dim Count As Variant
    Dim m As Variant

    Count = 1

    mark = Range("B1:B4").Value

    For Each m In mark

        Select Case m

            Case 0 To 35
            Range("C" + Trim(Str(Count))).Value = "Fail"

            Case 36 To 59
            Range("C" + Trim(Str(Count))).Value = "Pass"

            Case 60 To 79
            Range("C" + Trim(Str(Count))).Value = "Class"

            Case 80 To 89
            Range("C" + Trim(Str(Count))).Value = "Distinction"

            Case 90 To 100
            Range("C" + Trim(Str(Count))).Value = "Excellent"

            Case Else
            MsgBox "no text entered"

        End Select

        Count = Count + 1

    Next m

End Sub
```

Your `Range("C1:C4").Value = "Fail"`, etc. will update the entire range of values. You only need to update one or else if the last person has a 99 then everyone gets an excellent.

The `For Each` will cycle through each value and the `Count` will update the correct `C` cell

Comment: @Jeeped - declared variables :-P

Answer (score 2):

You are just trying to do four things at once. Use a loop to deal with each one at a time.

```
Sub Grades()

    Dim mark As Integer, markrng As Range

    For Each markrng In Range("B1:B4")
        If CBool(Len(markrng.Value)) And IsNumeric(markrng.Value) Then
            mark = CLng(markrng.Value)

            Select Case mark
                Case 0 To 35
                    markrng.Offset(0, 1) = "Fail"
                Case 36 To 59
                    markrng.Offset(0, 1) = "Pass"
                Case 60 To 79
                    markrng.Offset(0, 1) = "Class"
                Case 80 To 89
                    markrng.Offset(0, 1) = "Distinction"
                Case 90 To 100
                    markrng.Offset(0, 1) = "Excellent"
                Case Else
                    MsgBox "not a valid mark in " & markrng.Address(0, 0)
            End Select
        Else
            MsgBox "no mark entered in " & markrng.Address(0, 0)
        End If
    Next markrng

End Sub
```

To cover more potential errors, I've also added a check for non-numeric entries in addition to the missing grades.